# shallowMount behaves like mount when lazy loading a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm testing a Nuxt app with `vue-test-utils` (version 1.0.0-beta.29), and I'm lazy loading the `child` component. When testing, I want to `shallowMount` the `parent` component to stub the `child`s (I don't want to render the `child` component because of its dependencies).

Instead of creating `child` stubs, the whole component tree is rendering in the `shallowMount`. If I load the components without lazy loading, `shallowMount` works as expected.

It seems that the problem has already been faced and solved here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/959

I've tried to pass `{ shouldProxy: true }` as a mounting option, or stubbing manually the component by passing `{ stubs: ['componentname'] }`, but the problem is still happening.

`parent` component:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div 
      v-for="item in markets"
      class="item-wrapper">
      <Child :market="item"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    Child: () => import('./TimelineItem.vue')
  },
  props: {
    markets: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`child` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Child
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    market: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Snapshot:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div>Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div>Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected to have an snapshot like this:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <child-stub></child-stub>
  </div>
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <child-stub></child-stub>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue and I found working solution for me. Try to import components in your test file and add them in components sections..

`shallowMount(Component, { components: { Child }`)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to use a `dynamic component`.

```html
<div v-if='!Child'>Loading...</div>
<component v-if='Child' :is='Child' />
```

```js
<script>

export default {
  data: {
    Child:null,
  },
  created(){
     import('./TimelineItem.vue').then(it=>this.Child=it);
  }
}
</script>
```